Шаг задания агента MS SQL не выполняется
Агент MSSQL Server 2008 на сервере PULPNT40ASODU. Создан вложенный план для резервирования баз данных на другом сервере - Asodu_pulp_bw_v. Соответственно создано задание на Агенте для его выполнения.
Шаги задания следующие:

удаляю предыдущий бэкап на сервере посредством CmdExec:
del \\Asodu_pulp_bw_v\c$\Backup\*_backup_*.bak
выполнение Вложенного плана (создание резервной копии баз данных сервера Asodu_pulp_bw_v)
удаление предыдущих бэкапов с хранилища данных asodubackup:
del \\asodubackup\Backup\_ASODU\ASODU_PULP_BW\*.bak
копирую файлы с сервера в хранилище данных:
xcopy  /M/S/Y \\Asodu_pulp_bw_v\c$\Backup\*.bak \\asodubackup\Backup\_ASODU\ASODU_PULP_BW



Проблема: файлы не копируются в хранилище данных, если я запускаю задание с шага 1.
Если я запускаю задание с 4го шага, то файлы бэкапов копируются!
Пользователь, от имени которого запускается агент - имеет права администратора на asodu_pulp_bw_v и asodubackup.
Есть подобные задания, отрабатывают полностью. С этим не могу разобраться.

